# Point patterns analysis : clarkevans.test and edge correction

Tags: r, qgis, spatstat

First I'm really sorry because I'm newR, so I apologise if I missed a previous respond to this question, and I also apologise because I can not join pictures to my text (and I apologise for english fault because I'm not bilingual).

I'm working with Q-GIS and R. I have a forest (layer = parcels) with georeferenced specific trees (layer = coordinates of specific trees). I want to know if those specific trees are agregates. Therefore I import my Q-GIS layer on R which shows my specific trees (package rgdal, function readOGR).

Then I calculate the clark evans indice (package spatstat, function clarkevans.test) using the following line. Clark evans indice is the ratio of observed mean nearest neighbour distance to adjusted theoretical mean. (R=0 : complete agregation. R=1 : complete random. R=2.14914 : uniform pattern.)

```
clarkevans.test(PPP, correction="Donnelly", alternative="two.sided")
```

Where PPP is the format ppp of my layer specific trees :

```
PPP <- ppp(x = coordinates(spec_trees)[,1], y = coordinates(spec_trees)[,2], xrange = range(coordinates(spec_trees)[,1]), yrange = range(coordinates(spec_trees)[,2]))
```

And where the Donnelly correction is a correction for a rectangle window. I'm not sure if I have to use it or not. When there is no correction, I have almost the same result.

To the clark envans test, R responds :

```
R = 0.48929, p-value = 0.002
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Which means my points are significantly different from a spatial random distribution (p-value > 0.05) AND my points are agregates (R<1).

BUT, I think R might over estimates the agregation, and I need the true value. My forest (layer = parcels) is not a square or an oval. Parcels are discontinues (there are lakes, roads, houses) ! Trees can not be everywhere in the square, where there are no parcels, there can be no trees, so of course there are no specific_trees. But R does not know that, so it just search agregation of specific_trees in an empty square.
So my question is the following one : can I search the spatial pattern of points IN a limited area which has a complex shape ?

I hope I am clear, but do not hesitate to ask me questions.

Comment: Sounds like your observation window (region where trees have been surveyed) is a complex polygonal shape which you need to inform spatstat about in the call to ppp. Do you have the region in some standard format like shapefile or whatever?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I think you understood well the problem ! I have a shapefile containing all parcels (and 1 parcel = 1 polygon). But sometimes there are huge space between parcels, so the shapefile contains discontinues polygons. Can I use a disontinues layer of polygons in the PPP ranges ?

Comment: Yes you can use very general polygonal regions. Look at the help file and examples of owin()

Answer (score 0):

Since this question has been viewed many times, here is a detailed answer.

The analysis of a point pattern should always take account of the spatial region where points could have occurred. The `spatstat` package is designed to support this.

Point patterns are represented by objects of class `ppp`. The spatial region ("window") can be any complicated shape, or shapes, represented by an object of class `owin`.

You can create a point pattern in an irregularly-shaped window by

```
A <- ppp(x, y, window=W)
```

where `x` and `y` are vectors of coordinates, and `W` is a spatial region object of class `owin` created by the function `owin`. The object `W` can be a polygon, or several disconnected polygons, or a binary pixel mask, etc.

By the way, we **strongly discourage** the use of syntax like

```
PPP <- ppp(x, y, xrange = range(x), yrange = range(y))
```

because even when the spatial region is known to be a rectangle, it is unwise to estimate the limits of the rectangle by using the ranges of the coordinates.

For more information, see [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org).